# Laptop screen won't display if RAM slot is populated

Tags: laptop, memory, sodimm

**Context**: the laptop (IP3 14alc6) is configured in dual channel memory, 4GB soldered and a SODIMM slot:

[image]

When the SODIMM slot is populated the fan spins and only the screen backlight turns on. Only when pressure is applied to the ram stick, the screen works.

**My question is:** is it possible to solder a ram stick to the SODIMM slot to solve this issue ?

Comment: If you can solder accurately enough without melting anything important, you mean? Let's just call that a 'No', shall we? Clean the contacts with a can of contact cleaner [powered down & battery removed/disconnected]. Allow 24h before powering up, to be certain it's evaporated.

Comment: And make sure no contacts have been bent on the socket. *Sometimes*, bent contacts can be made to grip by *very careful* prying using a fine, bent, needle. And sometimes, that destroys them.

Comment: Are you sure you're inserting it correctly? SO-DIMMs often insert at 45° then you press flat & there's a solid click as they sit in place.

Comment: We're assuming you've worked with laptop RAM-sticks before & this is not your debut. ;-) Do not touch any component on the MB (including RAM) when you switch on the Laptop. SODIMM slot is not designed for soldering.